# how to set a marker in the GooglePlacesAutocomplete in react native

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I need help to solve this problem.

The problem is in the part that we search the address in the google place picker and then it automatically sets a marker/pin in the chosen location, but the marker set does not work yet...

The screen is:
Diurno.js
below is the entire code.

Here below is the search code:

```
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    placeholder="Outro Local?"
    placeholderTextColor="#333"
    returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key 
    //onPress={onLocationSelected}
    onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                this.props.notifyChange(details.geometry.location);
            }
            }
    query={{
      key: "",
      language: "pt"
    }}
        nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch'
        debounce={300}
    textInputProps={{
      onFocus: () => {
        this.setState({ searchFocused: true });
      },
      onBlur: () => {
        this.setState({ searchFocused: false });
      },
      autoCapitalize: "none",
      autoCorrect: false
    }}
    listViewDisplayed={searchFocused}
    fetchDetails ={true}
    enablePoweredByContainer={false}
```

Other code here:

```
        <MapView 
      //onPress={this.handleMapPress}
      onPress={this.handleMapPress}  
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      ref={map => this.mapView = map}
      rotateEnabled={true}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      showsMyLocationButton={true}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      zoomEnabled={true}
      showsPointsOfInterest={true}
      showBuildings={false} 
      //initialRegion={initialRegion}
      //region={region}
      initialRegion={region}
      provider="google"> 
      {!!props &&
       (<MapView.Marker
                coordinate={props.region}
               >         
        </MapView.Marker>
        )} 

      {!!location &&
       (<MapView.Marker
                coordinate={location}
               onPress={this.handleMarkerPress} 
               >    
        <Image source={isAddressVisible? placholder2: placholder} style={styles.icon} />         
        </MapView.Marker>
        )} 
    {this.state.coordinates.map((coordinates, index, title, description, location) =>(
      <MapView.Marker 
      onPress={this.handleMapPress} 
      ref={mark => coordinates.mark = mark}
      key={`coordinate_${index}`} 
      title={coordinates.title}
      description={coordinates.description} 
      coordinate={{
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude,
            }}
      >
      <Image source={isAddressVisible? placholder2: placholder} style={styles.icon} /> 
    </MapView.Marker>
    ))}
  </MapView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several issues in [your code](https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/react-native-maps-autocomplete). First, you're getting this error:

> _this.notifyChange is not a function.

You need to use `props` here:

```
onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
    this.props.notifyChange(details.geometry.location);
  }
}
```

Then, notice that you have commented out the `region` attribute from your `MapView` and that there is no `onRegionChange` either. If you add these:

```
region={this.props.region}
onRegionChange={(region) => this.props.onRegionChange(region)}
```

Your map now centers to the chosen place from Autocomplete predictions. But there is no marker, because you should also set its coordinate accordingly:

```
<MapView.Marker coordinate={this.props.region} />
```

I ran your app and after the above changes, your marker gets placed at the selected Autocomplete location. See screenshot below. :)

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of help. :) I'm not sure I understood your question though. Can you please clarify? Is the above solution not working for you?

Comment: hi guys, here is the final code, I think will help someone, this code have a purpose to get the address and the marker location by google place api... https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/react-native-maps-autocomplete

Comment: hi @evan, its works now, I past an ignition region to set a marker, and after a set manual marker by google places

Comment: That's great! Thx for sharing.

Comment: @Matheuscabral do please make sure you remove your api key though. You should regenerate it and restrict it going forward. See https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices

Comment: Thanks @Evan, I removed from now. :)

Comment: Nice, but please also remove the key from your original post's code and regenerate it asap.

Comment: Heya @Matheuscabral I'm gonna go on a trip from tomorrow until next Saturday and will leave my laptop at home so I won't be able to help so I hope someone else does. But if no one does, I'll definitely have a look at your new issue myself next weekend, please ping me 'cause I'll probably have forgotten by then lol. Have a nice day & week! :)

Comment: hi @Evan, thank you, anyone help me yet :/, can you help me?, after this, I had added a button location, but it is not working, can you support me with this too? :) I`m so glad

Comment: Hi there! It's a bummer that no one has answered you yet, I'm flying back home today so will be happy to take a look at your issue this weekend. In the meantime please make sure you post your full updated code and explain clearly what the problem is and what you wish to achieve so that we're on the same page as your question is a bit confusing to me atm. Thanks! @Matheuscabral

Comment: hi Evan I got a solution to this problem, now my  problem is when i set the function this.props.region, it can not find my location it returns to the chosen location by google places this is the new code:

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/react-native-maps-autocomplete

Comment: Hi Matheus, am still troubleshooting your other question, but i saw you deleted it? if you resolved it yourself first it would be better if you answered your own question for the community's sake, and for new issues please create a new question.

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221741/how-to-fit-a-zoom-in-the-specific-marker-in-react-native-and-can-select-any-othe