# How to fit a zoom in the specific marker in react native and can select any other marker in the map?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers

In this case when the app is initialize, the Pin-marker is set in the current position, but in the same map I have others markers, when I try to select other markers it fits again in the current position, how to solve this issue? I need to select any marker... and... When I find some place(with google places) it set a new marker and it set a new position and set the camera to the current search marker with zoom in this selected marker, and  my other problem was make a function to get the current location(device user) by a button... someone can help me???

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar hidden />
    <MapView
      onPress={this.handleMapPress}
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      ref={map => (this.mapView = map)}
      rotateEnabled={true}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      showsMyLocationButton={true}
      followsUserLocation={true}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      zoomEnabled={true}
      showsPointsOfInterest={true}
      showBuildings={false}
      //region={this.props.region}
      initialRegion={region}
      provider="google">
      {!!location && (
        <MapView.Marker
          coordinate={location}
          onPress={this.handleMarkerPress}>
          <Image
            source={isAddressVisible ? placholder2 : placholder}
            style={styles.icon}
          />
        </MapView.Marker>
      )}
      {this.state.coordinates.map(
        (coordinates, index, title, description, location) => (
          <MapView.Marker
            onPress={this.handleMapPress}
            ref={mark => (coordinates.mark = mark)}
            key={`coordinate_${index}`}
            title={coordinates.title}
            description={coordinates.description}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: coordinates.latitude,
              longitude: coordinates.longitude,
            }}>
            <Image
              source={isAddressVisible ? placholder2 : placholder}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          </MapView.Marker>
        )
      )}
      <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.props.region} >
          <Image
            source={ markerImage}
            style={styles.icon}
          />
      </MapView.Marker>
    </MapView>
```

here is the button to call the current location:

```
        <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={this.getlocation}
      style={styles.fab2}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/gps.png')}
              style={{
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                margin: 10,
                tintColor: 'white',
              }}
            />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Hey i tried to reproduce this but can't, with the code provided in your previous thread the map is already centered and zoomed into the marker, and this occurs whenever a new place is selected so i don't understand the issue, can you please edit your question to clarify what exactly isn't working at the moment?

Comment: Hi Evan, I have paste a initial region on the map-container.js to open directly in the map. So, now i change it,i put the empty region... but the issue continuous happening, i will try to show you, when I search something it change the position to the place searched but when I select other marker in other region in the map, it change again to selected reg

Comment: if I change <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.props.region}> to <MapView.Marker coordinate={region}> it permit that I select other markers in the other regions on the map, but when I search other region it do not fit the camera to this region, just the marker

Comment: and change the region={this.props.region} to region={region}...

Comment: and I tryed to make a button to move to the current location, but I can`t do it, i need a help for this too

Comment: if you open the snack and try to search some place and after this try to select other marker(handler(manually)) push in the map, it centered to the previous search place... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to this problem, here is the snack to your read...

here is the simple code bellow:

```
  pickLocationHandler = event => {
const coords = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;

this.map.animateToRegion({
  ...this.state.focusedlocation,
  latitude: coords.latitude,
  longitude: coords.longitude,
});

this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
    focusedlocation: {
      ...prevState.focusedlocation,

      latitude: coords.latitude,

      longitude: coords.longitude,
    },

    locationChosen: true,
  };
});
};

getLocationHandler = () => {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  pos => {
    const coordsEvent = {
      nativeEvent: {
        coordinate: {
          latitude: pos.coords.latitude,

          longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
        },
      },
    };

    this.pickLocationHandler(coordsEvent);
  },

  err => {
    console.log(err);

    alert(
      'Ocorreu um erro ao carregar sua localização, por favor ligue o GPS!'
    );
  }
 );
};
```

and I call this function at my created button:

```
        <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.getLocationHandler}
      style={styles.fab2}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/gps.png')}
              style={{
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                margin: 10,
                tintColor: '#FF3D00',
              }}
            />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is the link to the full code:

https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/react-native-maps-autocomplete---address---current-location-button

Please if this answered your possible problem, like it!! :)

Comment: Nice! So you used focusedlocation variable. I understand you're using [this repo](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) and followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@mohammad.nicoll/react-native-maps-with-autocomplete-e9c71e493974)?

Comment: I actually used the code you did to me, and I make it to work for my necessities. however, the command `this.props.region` function on the map does not allow me to select other pins, how could I set focus when searching? Can you help me?

Comment: if you open the fully code you will see that I commented this function...